# Renaming file if exists in Android

Tags: android

I have been looking at the forum and found some tips but none of them bring me to the final solution. I need the code if possible, please.

I am creating a txt file every time I close my app and what I am aiming for is to rename the file in case it already exists with the following format:

> file.txt - file(1).txt - file(2).txt

Up until now what I get is the following:

> file.txt - file.txt1 - file.txt12

The code that I have is the following:

```
int num = 0;
    public void createFile(String name) {  
    try {
        String filename = name;
        File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), filename);
        if (!myFile.exists()) {
            myFile.createNewFile();
        } else {
            num++;
            createFile(filename + (num));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks everybody in advance!

Comment: How do you call the `createFile` method? With which parameter?

Comment: createFile("FloodingFile.txt");

Comment: Whoever gave me a negative reputation for this question, thanks (IRONIC MODE ON). I don´t understand the reason. If it's because the code was not correctly indented, I tried many times to indent it correctly and I always got an error message. I think it was unfair that you give me negative points. Thanks to this person, I cannot vote positively to those that answer nicely my question. Thanks once again to whoever that was

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `filename` variable contains the whole name of your file (i.e. file.txt). So when you do this:

```
createFile(filename + (num));
```

It simply adds the number at the end of the file name.

You should do something like this:

```
int num = 0;

public void createFile(String prefix) {
    try {
        String filename = prefix + "(" + num + ").txt";  //create the correct filename
        File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), filename);

        if (!myFile.exists()) {
            myFile.createNewFile();
        } else {
            num++;               //increase the file index
            createFile(prefix);  //simply call this method again with the same prefix
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then just call it like this:

```
createFile("file");
```

Comment: Do you know how I can assign "only read" permissions to such file? At the moment, when I open the file, the user may edit the file. I would like to allow the user to only read it and not be able to modify the content of the file

Comment: Thanks but already had a look at such post and tried the answers but I can still make changes and save them...

Comment: Hi! I have just realized that this renaming issue works but the content of the files that already exist are modified. I mean, if already FloodingFile(0).txt exists and contains for example "abcd" and a new file is being created with "efgh", the name of the new created file will be FloodingFile(1).txt, which is correct, but the content of FloodingFile(0) is modified to "efgh". What is wrong here?

Comment: If I have written an answer to my own question is because previously I have written the same in a comment and I don't receive an answer. I though maybe it could me more visible by answering rather than by commenting. Maybe this would work better if instead of deleting posts, we answer comments and questions